# How to get machine specific Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

Tags: c#, .net, smo

I need to use Server class which is stored in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll` I don't see this assembly in usual References dialog. I have found it at `C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/SDK/Assemblies` and try to reference from there but Visual Studio throws an error

> A reference 'C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/SDK/Assemblies/Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies is the correct folder location.

You need to add references to:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll

Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll

Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll
```

(These are the minimum files that are required to build an SMO application)

Ref.: [How to: Create a Visual C# SMO Project in Visual Studio .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)